# What did I do wrong in my javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have no idea what is going wrong here. When I run this code on a website, it doesn't give an error.

It is meant to be ran from a bookmark in a browser to inject a script into a website, but I'm not getting the prompts to show.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';
document.body.appendChild(s);
if confirm('Press OK to enter a url to the script/nPress Cancel to enter code directly')
{
    s.src=prompt('Enter the url to the script file (javascript only):');
} else {
    s.innerhtml=prompt('Enter code to inject (javascript only):');
}
void(0);
```

This is the version of the code that will be ran from a bookmark.

```
javascript:var s = document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';document.body.appendChild(s);s.innerhtml=prompt('Enter code to inject (javascript only):');
```

Comment: are you sure it doesn't show any errors?  are you actually looking in the console?

Comment: Also, the property is `innerHTML` not `innerhtml`

Comment: @thescientist What console do you mean? I never saw a console. I ran this on firefox and didn't see an error. I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, but I'm fairly new to scripting in websites.

Comment: Firefox: Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console / Scratchpad. Chrome: Top-right menu thingy -> Tools -> JavaScript Console

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap `if` conditions in parentheses, eg

```
if (confirm('Press OK to enter a url to the script/nPress Cancel to enter code directly'))
```

The error I got with your original code was

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: how did you get the error? Was it from a browser? If so, how do you do it in firefox?

Comment: I pasted your JS into Chrome's console tab. You should be able to do the same with Firefox / Firebug

Comment: @user1193112 If you're using firefox you may want to take a look at http://getfirebug.com/